# Ruby on Rails testing with integration_test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, integration-testing

In my ruby on rails application when I run the following command I can't create required testing files.

```
rails generate integration_test named --integration-tool=rspec -s
```

I want to create the following files

```
  invoke  test_unit
  create    test/integration/named_test.rb
```

However, I get this message:

```
  invoke  rspec
```

I have the subsequent piece of code in my application:

```
  config.generators do |g|
    g.test_framework :rspec,
      fixtures: true,
      view_specs: false,
      helper_specs: false,
      routing_specs: false,
      controller_specs: false,
      request_specs: false
    g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: "spec/factories"
end
```

I can't see what I'm missing,

Any suggestions,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rspec seems to be your test framework as is in your config. That's why test_unit is not generating any file. On the other hand and IMO, rspec is much more suitable to run integration tests. Just follow any rspec tutorial out there.